# Кастомизация select'a, как задать расстояния между строками option в селекте?

Tags: html, cssselect, select, css, вёрстка

Как увеличить расстояния между строками в селекте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тег `<option>` нельзя кастомизировать. Используйте JS скрипты. Есть, например, хороший jQuery плагин - [Selectric](http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/)